# Is it possible to get scss variables declared in style block from js in vue via a vite plugin?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vite

I want to create a vite plugin in vue, which is able to get the scss/sass content in the `<style>` block, and extract its variables to a js object, then js can access these variables. For example:

```js
<script setup>
    const variables = getScssVariables(); // { foo: "30px", bar: "400ms" }
</script>
<template>
    <!-- -->
</template>
<style lang="scss">
    $foo: 30px;
    $bar: 400ms;

    // ...
</style>
```

Can this be achieved by creating a vite plugin?

Comment: The question is too broad for SO.You're limited to the usage of local sass vars, what about the ones that are imported?  It's likely possible but it would generate too much junk code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin:

put in vite.config.js or a separate file

```
plugins:[{

  load(id){

    if(!id.endsWith('.vue')){
      return;
    }

    const src = fs.readFileSync(id);

    // extract your scss vars from src
    // you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-parser

    // inject the vars:
    return src.replace('getScssVariables()', 'your css vars as object');

  }

}]
```